# AUVoiceProcessing unit kAUVoiceIOProperty_VoiceProcessingQuality deprecated

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

According to AudioUnitProperties.h, the kAUVoiceIOProperty_VoiceProcessingQuality is deprecated.  What is the replacement?

```
 @constant      kAUVoiceIOProperty_VoiceProcessingQuality
 @discussion        Scope: Global
                    Value Type: UInt32
                    Access: read/write
                DEPRECATED. Sets the quality of the voice processing unit. Quality values
                are comprised between 0 (lowest) and 127 (highest).
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
@constant       kAudioUnitProperty_RenderQuality
                    Scope:          Global
                    Value Type:     UInt32
                    Access:         Read / Write

                    A value (0 - 127) that can be used to control the quality (complexity) of the rendering operation. A typical usage is to set render quality to maximum for best quality, but
                    if CPU usage is a concern a lesser quality can be set to trade off render quality.
```

Comment: I have also been using that setting as well.  But don't think two are related.  Do you know what does kAudioUnitProperty_RenderQuality setting do?  The default value was 64.  I bumped it up to 127.  The manual does not seem to be very clear on this setting.

Comment: As far as I know you can use: kRenderQuality_Max, kRenderQuality_High, kRenderQuality_Medium, kRenderQuality_Low, kRenderQuality_Min